# How to bound $ P(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma^i X_i^2\ge ax)$ for eigenvalues of a normalized $N\times N$ GOE matrix?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a normalized $N\times N$ GOE matrix. Let $\sigma^1<\sigma^2<\dots <\sigma^N$. We know that the largest eigenvalue converges $\sigma^N$ to 2 almost surely. Assume that $X_1,\dots, X_N$ are iid random variables with law $\mu$ so that $E_{X\sim \mu}[e^{\alpha X}]<\infty$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Now, I try to prove that
$$
P(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma^i X_i^2\ge ax)\le \mbox{something like $(E[e^{\alpha X^2}])^N e^{-a\alpha xN}$}
$$
which goes to zero as $N\to \infty$.

---

My reasons for having this upper bound estimate are that if we consider the following thing: By Chebyshev's inequality
$$
P(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N  X_i^2\ge ax)=P(\exp(\alpha\sum_i X_i^2)\ge e^{a\alpha x N})\le \frac{(E[e^{\alpha X_0^2}])^N}{e^{a\alpha x N}} \to 0 
$$
as $N\to \infty$.

The inequality I want to prove has one more random variable $\sigma^i$ that is not easy to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have the joint law [GOE eigenvalues](https://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/%7Eleticia/TEACHING/Master2019/GOE-cuentas.pdf) density $\rho_{N}$

$$P[\sigma_{i}\in A_{i}]=\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{1}{Z_{N}}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}x_{i}^{2}}\prod_{k>m}|x_{k}-x_{m}|\prod dx_{i}$$

and so

$$P(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma^i X_i^2\ge at)=\iint_{R^{N}} P(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i} X_i^2\ge ax) \rho_{N}(x)dx$$
$$\leq \iint_{R^{N}}  \frac{\prod_{i}E[e^{\alpha x_{i} X_i^2}])}{e^{a\alpha t N}} \rho_{N}(x)dx.$$

To proceed from here one needs to know explicity the MGF for $X^{2}$ so as to estimate. Do you have any estimates for it at least?